# Atualizando uma coluna do tipo JSON no Postgres com Python e Psychopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

Ao tentar rodar um update como o abaixo no `postgres` via `psycopg2` do Python está dando o erro:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

Eu estou tentanto rodar um código como este:

```
self.cursor.execute("UPDATE tb_games set infos_json = %s where id = %s", (json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2:'b'}), id_game))
conexao.commit()
```

Minha coluna `infos_json` é do tipo `json`, o dicionário que estou passando para `json.dumps` é um dicionário válido, já validei o JSON em analisadores de código e tudo certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se esse trecho de código que você postou é o mesmo que está no programa, tem um erro nessa parte do código

```
json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2:'b'}), id_game)
                        ^ deveria ter um ' aqui`
```

experimente substituir por

```
self.cursor.execute("UPDATE tb_games set infos_json = %s where id = %s", (json.dumps({'v1':'a','v2':'b'}), id_game))
conexao.commit()
```